# Smartface framework CodeReader

Tags: smartface.io

i use smartface.io ,how can i use front mobile cam with CodeReader in android application [enter link description here](http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/controls/codereader/)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use codeReader wiht front cam. 
You can check some codeReader applications, I guess back cam is the common usage for it.